# Expressing $ \sum_{\lambda\in\text{Spec}(\mathbf{X})} \lambda \log \lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, power-series, numerical-linear-algebra

Say $\text{Spec}(\mathbf{X})$ is a set of eigenvalues of a real positive definite matrix $\mathbf{X}$.

How do I express
$$ \sum_{\lambda\in\text{Spec}(\mathbf{X})} \lambda \log \lambda$$
without explicitly finding the eigenvalues?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy

Comment: How about $\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{X}\log \mathbf{X})$ ?  For this we have to count the eigenvalues **with multiplicity**.